# Not able to find the "TcmTemplateDebugHost" process in Attach process, Even we run the Template builder

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, template-builder

We are trying to follow the steps which are mentioned in the document.
[Debugging .NET assembly Template Building Blocks](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-05CAD6E3-2CC0-4846-AB72-0F062A07C844?)
But we are not able to find the "TcmTemplateDebugHost" Process in the "Attach to Process dialog" box.

Answer (score 8):

In order to debug against the "TcmTemplateDebugHost" locally, you need to setup Remote Debugging (link below). If you have access to the CM server itself, you can also run Template Builder on the CM and debug directly against the TcmTemplateDebugHost process assuming Template Builder is running.

There used to be some extensions required which would run the SDL Tridion Content Manager render/publishing engine in a local context, but SDL now provides a way to do this out of the box.

You can find the [documentation here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-2FCC6253-71C7-4643-A1C0-0E2C38FB3358) explaining how to debug remotely. But basically you just need to run the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on the CM server, and then you should be able to open Visual Studio and Template Builder locally and attach to the remote process running on the CM server.

You do need to actually execute a TBB in Template Builder for the process to spin up. You should see in Template Builder (assuming logging is on Debug) the id of the process which was started:

> Debugging was started in process 'TcmTemplateDebugHost' with id 12716

Once you see that line, you can verify on the CM server that the process is running in the Details tab of Task Manager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: + don't forget to click 'show processes from all users'

Comment: Hi @Josh Hebb, Thanks for your replay, we will check and let you know if we face any issues.

Comment: Hi @AtilaSos, Yes we did the mentioned step, still no luck.

Comment: Hi @Josh Hebb, I could not find “Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (msvsmon.exe)” on CM server. It is present on Local where visual studio is installed. Below is the path of "msvsmon.exe" where it is present. Path: <VisualStudioInstallationPath>\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\.  It seems the solution will work when VS, template builder is present on CM server as you mentioned in answer. We guess this exe should be available only where the VS is installed. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: Hi @SreeG. I think that is true, but I believe you can also install "Visual Studio Remote Tools" without having to install a full version of Visual Studio which isn't really needed on the CM server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks @Josh Hebb, We will work on this and let you if need further assistance.

Comment: Hi @JoshHebb, Thanks for sharing the information, Even we fallowed the Steps that you have provided, we are not able to see the "TcmTemplateDebugHost" process in Attach Process Dialogue box. If you have any further information please share.